# Why does the Range() method in Python have an optional parameter yet its second parameter is not optional?

Tags: python, range

Newbie here, as I understand you cannot have non-optional arguments after optional ones, so when I saw the documentation for the range() method I was quite confused. What is going on here, am I missing something?

It says the start parameter is optional and defaults to 1, but the second parameter stop is mandatory.

Link to range() function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: Really it has two different signatures. If you pass 2 or 3 parameters it uses the second signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the number of arguments range is passed the behavior changes.

- If 1 argument is passed it treats the start as implicit and the only argument as the stop value.
- If 2 arguments are passed it treats the first argument as the start value and the second as the stop value.
- If 3 arguments are passed it treats the first argument as the start value, the second as the stop value, and the third as the step size.

Below is a contrived and probably buggy example of how such a function could be implemented:

```py
def myrange(arg1, arg2=None, arg3=None):
    if not arg2:
        return range(arg1)
    if not arg3:
        return range(arg2, arg1)
    return range(arg2, arg1, arg3)
```

Answer (score 2):

The doc lists two cases:

```
class range(stop)
class range(start, stop[, step])
```

So if you pass only one argument, the first case pertains; the function interprets the argument as `stop`.

If you pass more than one argument, the second case pertains; the function interprets the first argument as `start`, and so on.

In either case, optional argument (`[step]`) follows mandatory arguments. Just the interpretation of the "first argument" is different in two cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to implement a function with different signatures (like range()) yourself, you could do it like this:

```
def myRange(*args):
    if   len(args) == 1: start,stop,step    = 0,*args,1
    elif len(args) == 2: start,stop,step    = *args,1
    else:                start,stop,step,*_ = args
    print(start,stop,step)
    # ... work with start, stop, step ..
```

Answer (score 2):

It's true that you cannot have non optional after optional arguments unless if you use kwargs, but range is a special class that's a built-in to python and its source is actually written in C. So range is a special one where if you:

- pass in one argument its stop (it assumes start of 0 and step 1)
- pass in two arguments it's start, stop (assuming step 1)
- pass in three arguments it's start, stop, step

In normal python functions, and classes, though afaik you can't override the order like that. Unless if you use a wrapper function that keeps track of the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Range takes up to three (unnamed) parameters - *start*, *end* and *step*.

If you pass just one parameter then *start* is assumed to be zero and the given parameter is *end*.

Thus, for example, range(5) is exactly the same as range(0,5).

However, if you want to provide a *step* value, you will have to pass all three parameters even if *start* is intended to be zero - e.g., range(0, 10, 2)